# How can I get my layout boxes to wrap responsively?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, margin

I am currently studying HTML, CSS, and JS on Coursera. I have been given the assignment to reproduce a responsive webpage using very simple HTML and CSS without using frameworks, grid, flex, and JS. I have mostly finished coding the page, but now I am stuck with two problems that, I believe, are connected to margins and viewport. The page should respond to the size of the screen like that:

1. Desktop: the three boxes should each take a third of the page horizontally
2. Tablet: the first two boxes should take the half of the screen and the third should take 100% of the next line
3. Mobile: the three boxes should stack

I can recreate the Desktop and Mobile view but not the Tablet. In my Tablet view, the third covers the first two. I am using media queries for that. I have attached my HTML and CSS code.

And the other problem has something to do with margins. I need to apply even spacing between the boxes. However, when I use margins in Desktop view, the third box drops on the next line. So, I have omitted them.
Here is a link to the task on GitHub https://github.com/jhu-ep-coursera/fullstack-course4/blob/master/assignments/assignment2/Assignment-2.md in case my explanation is not clear.

Thanks in advance. I am a noob but I want to learn and improve.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  background-color: #ffb3ff;
}

body {
  font-family: "Truculenta", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.75em;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.box {
  background: #ffffe6;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

p {
  padding: 40px 10px 4px 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.label {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
}

#label1 {
  background: #73e600;
}

#label2 {
  background: #ff0055;
}

#label3 {
  background: #00bfff;
}


/* Desktop */

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 2560px) {
  .box {
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
  }
}


/* Tablet */

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  div#box1.box {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
  div#box2.box {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
  div#box3.box {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* Mobile */

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .box {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Coursera Module 2 Assignment - Restaurant Menu</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Truculenta" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Our Menu</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="box1" class="box">
      <div class="label">
        <h3 id="label1">Chicken</h3>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="box2" class="box">
      <div class="label">
        <h3 id="label2">Beef</h3>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="box3" class="box">
      <div class="label">
        <h3 id="label3">Sushi</h3>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

Comment: I'd strongly encourage you to abandon floats for layout. They're an outdated technique and not ideal. There are much better ways.

Comment: The task says that I have to use the simplest technique possible, and it is based on the lectures I went through. I know that it is way better to use Grid for that task, but I am limited here. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Define "simple". Fighting with old techniques and ending up with obsolete code is the opposite of simple to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make your code work with two things:

- Convert all instances of float to inline-block display
- Remove whitespace between the three `.box` elements in the markup

However, I'd look at using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) for a modern solution.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  background-color: #ffb3ff;
}

body {
  font-family: "Truculenta", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.75em;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ffffe6;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

p {
  padding: 40px 10px 4px 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.label {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
}

#label1 {
  background: #73e600;
}

#label2 {
  background: #ff0055;
}

#label3 {
  background: #00bfff;
}


/* Desktop */

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 2560px) {
  .box {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}


/* Tablet */

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  div#box1.box {
    width: 50%;
  }
  div#box2.box {
    width: 50%;
  }
  div#box3.box {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* Mobile */

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .box {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Coursera Module 2 Assignment - Restaurant Menu</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Truculenta" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Our Menu</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="box1" class="box">
      <div class="label">
        <h3 id="label1">Chicken</h3>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
    </div><div id="box2" class="box">
      <div class="label">
        <h3 id="label2">Beef</h3>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
    </div><div id="box3" class="box">
      <div class="label">
        <h3 id="label3">Sushi</h3>
      </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: However, I still cannot apply even spacing between the boxes((. I feel really stupid. When I add margin to .box the last column breaks on the next line and I get some ugly space in the right corner of the screen.

Comment: Use interior divs to space off the edges of the structural divs with padding or margin. This is where the modern solutions prove beneficial.